# Entity Framework cascade delete - cycles or multiple cascade paths

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have 4 classes

- **Component** - contains info about classes and interfaces
- **Class**, **Interface** - both contain list of methods
- **Method**

Each **component** contains more **classes** and **interfaces**, each **class** and **interface** has more **methods**.

If I remove **component** I need to remove also **classes**, **interfaces** and their **methods**. Can you give me a hint how to configure **OnModelCreating** in order to solve that? It seems problematic having **method** for both **class** and **interface**.

I'm getting this error:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'Interface_Methods' on table
>   'Methods' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON
>   DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY
>   constraints. Could not create constraint.

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {


         modelBuilder.Entity<Component>().
           HasMany(t => t.Classes).
           WithOptional().
           WillCascadeOnDelete();

        modelBuilder.Entity<Component>().
           HasMany(t => t.Interfaces).
           WithOptional().
           WillCascadeOnDelete();


        modelBuilder.Entity<Class>().
           HasMany(t => t.Methods).
           WithOptional().
           WillCascadeOnDelete();

       modelBuilder.Entity<Interface>().
          HasMany(t => t.Methods).
          WithOptional().
          WillCascadeOnDelete();


        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<ForeignKeyAssociationMultiplicityConvention>();

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
```

Component:

```
public class Component
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Class> Classes { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Interface> Interfaces { get; set; }

    public Component()
    {
        Classes = new List<Class>();
        Interfaces = new List<Interface>();
    }
}
```

Class:

```
public class Class
{
    [Key]  
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Method> Methods { get; set; }

    public Class()
    {
        Methods = new List<Method>();
    }
}
```

Interface:

```
public class Class
{
    [Key]  
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Method> Methods { get; set; }

    public Class()
    {
        Methods = new List<Method>();
    }
}
```

Method:

```
public class Method
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since a method can be referenced by any number of classes and interfaces, I don't think you would want it to be deleted if one of those classes or interfaces was deleted.  Instead, consider having a the Component own the methods and delete them.

I have not used EF code first so the syntax of this code may not be correct, but hopefully gets the point across:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Component>().
    HasMany(t => t.Classes).
    WithOptional().
    WillCascadeOnDelete();

modelBuilder.Entity<Component>().
    HasMany(t => t.Interfaces).
    WithOptional().
    WillCascadeOnDelete();

modelBuilder.Entity<Component>().
    HasMany(t => t.Methods).
    WithOptional().
    WillCascadeOnDelete();

modelBuilder.Entity<Class>().
    HasMany(t => t.Methods).
    WithOptional();

modelBuilder.Entity<Interface>().
    HasMany(t => t.Methods).
    WithOptional();
```